# Window water damage

Tags: water-damage

first time home owner here.  Window has water damage (exterior side was facing sprinkler).  I have capped off the sprinkler and caulked the external side.  what should I do about the interior ?

[image]

Comment: What am I looking at? I think that I see a vinyl window with trim hiding the gap between the window and an adjacent wall surface. If so, then you'll want to carefully remove the trim if it's salvageable. Then you'll want to repair or replace the damaged wall surface. If that wall surface is concrete, then I'd remove any chips and use hydraulic cement as putty to repair the craters. I wouldn't be surprised if that window needs insulating foam around its perimeter while you have access. That, not caulk, is how to kill any drafts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details.. the wall surface is wood I believe but I need to check

Comment: pretty sure that's a brittle material. After your comment, I'm betting that somebody slathered joint compound between the window's trim and the adjacent walls to bury something offensive. You'll want to carefully remove the trim so that you can reuse it (_very_ carefully, as it sounds like creating a replacement might be beyond your skills). Then snap a picture of the edge of that adjacent surface.

Comment: Second @popham comment.  you will need to remove trim to see if any more damage to the wall/frame has been done.  Take pictures.  Depending on your sale contract that might be considered known damage, that the sellers might be liable for.  Possible that is the only problem shown in the picture and cheaper to fix.  It is any hidden damage that might cost.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing you did with the exterior:

1. Scrape loose paint, sand if necessary. Remove any old caulk.
2. Add new caulk.
3. Paint.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check how to the sanding and add new caulk

Comment: I checked all the windows in the home and they all use this joint compound between window trim and wall.. the house was built in 1965.  maybe this is common for construction during that time ?

Comment: @user174892 It's not uncommon. But the damage in the picture seems cosmetic to me, so the remedy is still just caulk and paint. If you are getting drafts of cold air, then it might be time to remove the windows and reinstall them using foam, add new trim, etc. But if you are doing all of this work, might as well install a modern window with good insulation properties.